# Modify CDC Schema In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

Can we add a column in CDC captured tables?

Basically we are going to process CDC rows and we want to tracked which rows are already processed. So we are thinking about adding a bit field to the CDC table and whenever that row is processed from our service we will update this bit?

Is it safe? Or are there any disadvantages/problems in doing this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This question strikes me as fairly clear! The OP is asking if adding a bit (or any?) field to a CDC table could potentially cause problems - I think this shoudl be fairly simple and straigtforward for those who are proficient in SQL Server (I'm not, so I can't answer).